# Avoiding assembly file locks with Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: c#, sql-server

Adding `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` to an existing web project so that we can use the `DBGeography` and `DBGeometry` spacial types from NuGet adds native assemblies to the project and includes a `Loader` that looks something like this:

```
public class Utilities
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the required native assemblies for the current architecture (x86 or x64)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootApplicationPath">
    /// Root path of the current application. Use Server.MapPath(".") for ASP.NET applications
    /// and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for desktop applications.
    /// </param>
    public static void LoadNativeAssemblies(string rootApplicationPath)
    {
        var nativeBinaryPath = IntPtr.Size > 4
            ? Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, @"SqlServerTypes\x64\")
            : Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, @"SqlServerTypes\x86\");

        LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "msvcr120.dll");
        LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "SqlServerSpatial140.dll");
    }

    private static void LoadNativeAssembly(string nativeBinaryPath, string assemblyName)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(nativeBinaryPath, assemblyName);
        var ptr = LoadLibrary(path);
        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(
                "Error loading {0} (ErrorCode: {1})",
                assemblyName,
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }
    }
}
```

Which then has to be called from our `global.asax.cs` like this:

```
SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName =
    "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~"));
```

(the first line being found only after some digging).

This all works fine locally, and works fine once we deploy...but, the problem is that when we redeploy our project those native assemblies are locked and that breaks the build. The worker process has to be stopped and restarted before deployment can happen and it is a major pain.

So my question is, is there a better way to handle this? The readme.htm that gets downloaded with the NuGet package suggests that you need to deploy the native assemblies to *a machine that does not have 'System CLR Types for SQL Server' installed* but doesn't quite elaborate on what, if anything, you need to do to install that and what you might need to change if you do.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. For our website we had update the publish profile to set EnableMSDeployAppOffline to true which cause the site to shut down during the deployment.

Then on the termination of the website event we release the dlls using the FreeLibrary method. This seems to work for us.